# Can't get Python / Livestreamer to run on Windows 8.1

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Livestreamer working on a Windows 8.1 machine and have followed all the installation instructions for Python, PiP and Livestreamer and it all seems to be installed correctly.

However when I try run it I get the followng

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\livestreamer-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('livestreamer==1.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'livestreamer')()

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\livestreamer-1.7.2-py2.7.egg\livestreamer_
cli\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from livestreamer import (Livestreamer, StreamError, PluginError,
ImportError: cannot import name Livestreamer
```

I've tried adding my Python directory to the path and executing it under an admin CMD but still nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install Livestreamer from source or using the Windows installer? According to the docs, you don't need to install any dependencies. The error you are getting is saying it cannot find the Livestreamer library.

From: http://livestreamer.tanuki.se/en/latest/install.html

> Windows Livestreamer is primarily developed for Unix-like operating
>   systems where using a CLI is common. There is however a installer
>   available for brave Windows users who don’t mind using the command
>   prompt.
>
> The installer can be downloaded from Github. It contains a precompiled
>   version of Livestreamer that does not require you to install any of
>   the dependencies.

Comment: and I'm an idiot for not seeing the windows installer... thanks easy points :)